# How to zoom in on a specific graph node and change the fillcolor using Microsoft GLEE?

Tags: c#, graph, microsoft-glee

I am using Microsoft Glee to draw a graph with many nodes and edges. I would like to have a search box, where when i search for the node's name, it would zoom in on that node and change the fillcolor, so that it is easier to spot the node.

The current code i have is zooming in reasonably, but it doesn't change the fillcolor of the node. Any ideas?

```
Node n =  gViewer.Graph.FindNode(myNodeID);
n.Attr.Fillcolor = Microsoft.Glee.Drawing.Color.Red;
n.Attr.Color = Microsoft.Glee.Drawing.Color.Red;    
gViewer.ShowBBox(n.BBox);
gViewer.Invalidate();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it has to do with the shape of the node. If the shape was ellipsis, it didn't work. I changed the shape to a box and it works fine